# Rails 4.1 Mailer Previews and Devise custom emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a brand new Rails 4.1.1 app where I'm customizing the Devise emails. I want to have them displayed on the new Rails email preview feature so I did the following:

1) Added the following snippet to my `config/development.rb` file:

```
config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/lib/mailer_previews"
```

2) Created my custom Devise email `UserMailer` in `app/mailers/user_mailer.rb`:

```
class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer   
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`

  layout "notifications_mailer"
end
```

3) Changed `config/initializers/devise.rb` to contain the following snippet:

```
config.mailer = 'UserMailer'
```

4) Added the class `UserMailerPreview` to `lib/mailer_previews` with the following content:

```
class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def confirmation_instructions
    UserMailer.confirmation_instructions(User.first, {})
  end

  def reset_password_instructions
    UserMailer.reset_password_instructions(User.first, {})
  end

  def unlock_instructions
    UserMailer.unlock_instructions(User.first, {})
  end
end
```

So far, so good. Looks like I've done everything right. But then I try to see the preview for the `confirmation_instructions` email at the /rails/mailers/user_mailer/confirmation_instructions route and I get the following error:

```
undefined method `confirmation_url' for #<#<Class:0x007fa02ab808e0>:0x007fa030fb7e80>
```

the code for my `confirmation_url.html.erb` template looks like this:

```
<%= t("notifications.texts.greeting") + @user.display_name %>,

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token =>  @token) %></p>
```

What am I doing wrong? I guess it is something wrong with the way I call the `confirmation_url` method. Anyone can help me here?

Comment: Where do you call `confirmation_url`? Can you share the relevant code where you are getting this error.

Comment: ah, in the view. Updated the post

Comment: I followed @steel's suggestions and got it working. Also I had to restart the server for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this question because I was trying to figure out how to preview Devise emails myself. I copied your code almost exactly and it works fine for me.

The only thing I did differently was to remove the line `layout "notifications_mailer"` from `UserMailer` - when I included it I got an error message `Missing template layouts/notifications_mailer`. What happens if you remove it?

The line `Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers` definitely includes the method `confirmation_url` (you can see this for yourself by opening up the Rails console and running `include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers` then `confirmation_url`, so I suspect the problem is that your previews aren't being rendered by `UserMailer` at all. I'm not sure why, but the line `layout "notifications_mailer"` might be the culprit.

Do you have a class called `NotificationsMailer`? Does including `Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers` in there solve your problem?

Answer (score 64):

For those looking to preview Devise emails without using custom mailers, (but still custom emails) this is what I did:

1. Configure your app for email previewing.
2. Set up the Devise Mailer Preview class

   a. Rails ~> 4.1

   ```
   # mailer/previews/devise_mailer_preview.rb
   class Devise::MailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview

     def confirmation_instructions
       Devise::Mailer.confirmation_instructions(User.first, "faketoken")
     end

     def reset_password_instructions
       Devise::Mailer.reset_password_instructions(User.first, "faketoken")
     end

     ...

   end
   ```

   b. Rails ~> 5.0

   ```
   class DeviseMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview

     ... # same setup as Rails 4 above
   ```
3. Restart the server

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked. I don't yet know how to test reset_password_instructions because I don't know which arguments to pass. PS: You have to indent one more level because the code is within the list.

Comment: @Besi, thanks for the format help. To test the password reset, just pass it a user and a string, like this: Devise::Mailer.reset_password_instructions(User.first, "faketoken")

Comment: But as I'm here, what's the url ? I did config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/app/mailers/previews", but http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers returns nothing :/

Comment: I can't confirm your port, obviously, but that's the relative path.

Comment: Try this `localhost:3000/rails/mailers/devise/mailer/`

Answer (score 7):

You will get undefined method for the devise url helpers when you have forgotten to include the necessary devise modules in your model. e.g. if your model is `User` and you want the `confirmation_url`, you must ensure that the `:confirmable` module is included:

```
devise <...snipped...>, :confirmable
```

Be aware that if this module is *not* currently loaded that your application most likely does not use e.g. confirmations!

Including the :confirmable module might then lock out all your users. See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users

Answer (score 7):

Using Rails 5 and found the syntax slightly different from @steel's excellent answer, with the use of double "::" being the difference:

```
# Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/devise_mailer
class DeviseMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview

    def reset_password_instructions
        Devise::Mailer.reset_password_instructions(User.first, "faketoken")
    end
end
```

Comment: When using gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.6', it is working with :: only. Without :: getting 'Mailer preview 'devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions' not found'