# Devise: welcome mail preview with confirmation link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

- rails 4.2.5
- ruby 2.3

I'm using Devise and sending two emails to users.

- after signup (welcome with confirmation link)
- after changing email (with confirmation link)

Both are sent with a custom Devise Mailer:

```
class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer
    layout 'email'
    helper :application
    include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers

    def confirmation_instructions(record, token, options={})
        if record.pending_reconfirmation?
            options[:template_name] = 'confirmation_instructions'
        else
            options[:template_name] = 'welcome_email'
        end
        super
    end
end
```

I can preview the Devise default emails whitout problem (*confirmation_instructions*, *reset_password_instructions* or unlock_instructions). My question is all about a custom email preview (*welcome_email* with *confirmation_url*).

How to **preview the welcome_email with confirmation_url** in my UserMailerPreview? Is it possible or should I change my aprouch?

My preview so far:

```
class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
    def confirmation_instructions
        UserMailer.confirmation_instructions(User.first, '123456', {})
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly your question, but there's a great gem to preview emails: https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716397/rails-4-1-mailer-previews-and-devise-custom-emails

Comment: @akz92 Actually since Rails 4.2.1 we have a feature to do this without any gem. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#action-mailer-previews

Comment: @miloshes I can preview those Devise default emails normally (confirmation_instructions, reset_password_instructions or unlock_instructions). My question is all about a custom email preview (welcome_email with confirmation_url).