# Preview devise mailer not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I try to have a preview of devise mailer but when it doesn't work.

I have followed this [rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#previewing-emails) and it doesn't seems difficult and many things to do.

Devise already have a mailer class [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb)

So I should only have to create a preview file so here is what I have done so far.

I generated my devise views in the repository `app/views/users/mailer/`

I have my `devise.rb`which look like that

```
Devise.setup do |config|
# ==> Mailer Configuration
  # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in Devise::Mailer,
  # note that it will be overwritten if you use your own mailer class
  # with default "from" parameter.
  config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'
  # Configure the parent class responsible to send e-mails.
  #config.parent_mailer = 'ActionMailer::Base'
end
```

I have my `test/mailers/previews/devise_mailer_preview.rb`

```
class DeviseMailerPreview< ActionMailer::Preview

  def confirmation_instructions
    Devise::Mailer.confirmation_instructions(User.first, "faketoken")
  end

  def reset_password_instructions
    Devise::Mailer.reset_password_instructions(User.first, "faketoken")
  end

end
```

I didn't change the path `config.action_mailer.preview_path`in my `application.rb` because `test/mailers/previews` is the default path

So now when I try to access to `http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers` I have a white empty page
and if I try `http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/users/mailer/confirmation_instructions` I have this error `Mailer preview 'users/mailer/confirmation_instructions' not found`

I tried many different link but still have the same error, I also tried to followed this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25860079) but no success.

It's seems so easy but I can't succeed ...

Comment: `config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'` provides a hint to the issue. You should be accessing the preview in a devise directory. And maybe your class should be `Devise::MailerPreview`

Comment: Sadly it still doesn't work ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found out why.

Because I'm using the gem `rspec-rails` the repository `test` is replaced tp `spec`
I just needed to move my `test/mailers/previews/devise/mailer_preview.rb`to `spec/mailers/previews/devise/mailer_preview.rb` and still not need to change the configuration of `config/application.rb`

Hope it will help some people

also note that in rails 6 your devise mailer preview should be wrote with a module

```
module Devise
class MailerPreview< ActionMailer::Preview

  def confirmation_instructions
    Devise::Mailer.confirmation_instructions(User.first, "faketoken")
  end

  def reset_password_instructions
    Devise::Mailer.reset_password_instructions(User.first, "faketoken")
  end

end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving the mailers folder worked for me!

Comment: it should be a comment rather than a answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30063498)